# Remove one "return to my profile" instance and change to "return to my CV"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I don't think its necessary to have multiple links for this, the distance between the two did not cause any form of arthritis.

Also rename to "return to my CV"

This page could also use some CSS luvin / design

## Add Project

Is

## HUGE

[image]

This also applies to "Add books", "Add projects", "Add applications" and anything on the CV page that takes you to an add page.  They all look the same.

Comment: Fixed! Live on the next prod build.

Comment: @Donna- Great can't wait to see it.